# Realizar mapeamento do banco de dados para DbSet<T>.SqlQuery()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Erro ao executar o SqlQuery do meu DbSet.

> Não existe mapeamento do tipo de objeto System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectParameter para um provedor gerenciado de tipo nativo.

Eu gostaria de deixar meu banco de dados genérico, por isso coloquei os parâmetro como ObjectParameter, como realizo esse mapeamento de ObjectParameter para SqlParameter?

```
    public static ICollection<T> GetMany(string where, params object[] parameters)
    {
        object[] objParameters = new object[parameters.Count()];

        Type type = typeof(T);
        DbSet<T> dbSet = _context.Set<T>();

        string sql = " SELECT * FROM " + type.Name.ToUpper() + " WHERE " + where;

        int startPosition = 0;
        int stopPosition = 0;
        int contador = 0;

        //Colocar espaço apenas para controle.
        sql = sql.Insert(sql.Length, " ");

        // Montar Parametros.
        for (int i = 0; i < sql.Length; i++)
        {
            if (sql[i] == '@')
            {
                startPosition = i + 1;
                for (int a = i; a < sql.Length; a++)
                {
                    if (sql[a] == ' ')
                    {
                        stopPosition = a + 1;
                        string nomeParameter = sql.Substring(startPosition, stopPosition - startPosition);
                        ObjectParameter parameter = new ObjectParameter(nomeParameter.Trim(), parameters[contador]);
                        objParameters[contador] = parameter;
                        contador++;
                        break;                            
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        var registros = dbSet.SqlQuery(sql, objParameters).ToArray<T>();

        if (registros != null)
            return registros;
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Sendo T uma entidade mapeada no EF, você poderia fazer dessa forma:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where = null)
{
    IQueryable<T> query = Db.Set<T>();

    if (where != null)
    {
        query = query.Where(where);
    }

    return query.AsNoTracking().ToList();
}
```

A chamada desse metodo seria algo assim:

```
var lista = GetMany(p => p.AlgumaPropriedade == algumValor);
```

EDIT:
A IQueryable é uma interface herdada de IEnumerable, assim como IList, por exemplo, [conforme pode ser visto nesse link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.linq.iqueryable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Já a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` é o mesmo parametro que o Where do Linq utiliza.

Você deve utilizar uma instância da classe onde colocou o método GetMany.

Comment: Anderson, não consegui compreender muito seu código, eu nunca usei o Queryable, e também nunca usei o Expression<Func<T,bool>>, poderia me explicar um pouco mais afundo ?

Comment: var t = Entity<Paises>.GetMany(x => x.Descricao == "ALEMANHA"); Realizei a chamada: mas o seguinte erro. (Error 2 Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type C:\Users\Nicola Bogar\Desktop\Software\Powerade.ERP.Aplicacao\Powerade.ERP.Aplicacao\Form1.cs 38 44 Powerade.ERP.Aplicacao
)